# Communication between two hosts both on a different network connected to the same switch

Tags: networking, router, nic

How can I make two machines on a different network, connected to the same switch, communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu you can use ssh command to communication.

for this install open-ssh server (follow this link)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

then use sudo ssh user@IP Address

be sure that firewall is disable

Comment: I edited the question please check it. 192.168.1.63 is one host and 192.168.1.54 is another host connected to same switch. If i do ping it will work or not?

Comment: Thank you but am unable to check this because am not having this kind of network connection. Just i asked to know theory concept thank you

Answer (score 0):

if there is no DHCP server, you would have to configure the IP Adresses manually on the devices

Comment: I edited the question please check it. 192.168.2.63 is one host and 192.168.1.54 is another host connected to same switch. If i do ping it will work or not?

Comment: it now depends on your submask, how it divides the networks

Comment: yeah both host have different network address , Will i able to communicate between those hosts

Comment: what is your submask? 255.255.255.0 should work iirc, turn off your firewall so you get ICMP Ping request forwarded (idk your system at the moment)

Comment: my default subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 its Class C ip address